# Laurent series expansion of $f(z) = \cfrac{z^2-1}{z^3} - z + 1$ at the origin

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I started complex analysis a few weeks ago and we have arrived at the Laurent series! There was this exercise that I was having some trouble with!

---

> Determine the Laurent expansion of the function $$f(z) = \cfrac{z^2-1}{z^3} -z + 1$$ at $z_0 = 0$ and characterize the singularity.

---

I "simplified" the expression and found that $z_0$ is  a pole of order 3!  What im confused on how to do is how do I find the residue point $\mbox{Res}(f,0)$?

Can you help me find it in this case and maybe if possible how do i do that in general! I am kinda confused at that point!

Comment: I had never encountered a question on Mathematics SE with so many `!`'s. Glad to see that you're really excited about complex analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the residue is just the coefficient of the simple pole.
$$f(z)=\frac{z^2-1}{z^3}-z+1=\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z^3}-z+1$$
So the residue $Res_{z=0} f(z)=1$ the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$.

Comment: W8 is that it?Damn that was embarasing! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Im sorry to ask but im new at this! But just to be sure! A function can have multiple poles right? And those of order 1 are considered simple right?

Comment: No problem asking and yes, you can have poles wherever you want.  The ones of order one are called simple and they are special because of the way they behave when you integrate around them.

Comment: thanks a lot! This helped

Answer (score 1):

The Laurent series is $f(z)=\frac  1 z -\frac1  {z^{3}} -z+1$ and the residue is the coefficient of $\frac 1 z$ which is $1$.